# How to mathematically deal with unexpected negative value

Tags: mathematical-physics

For planck’s photon energy equation when calculating wavelength it makes no sense for it to be negative.

The answer I get is negative because the energy value is the only negative variable, heat is given out so it’s said that the reaction is exothermic heat taken in is positive.

Units:

$h=6.262\cdot 10^{-34}\ j\cdot s^{-1}$

$c=2.998\cdot 10^{8}\ m\cdot s^{—1}$

${NA}=6.022\cdot 10^{23}\ mol^{-1}$

$E=-533000\ j\cdot mol^{-1}$

$\lambda=x\cdot m$

$$
\lambda=\frac{h\cdot c\cdot {NA}}{E}=\frac{h\cdot c}{E}
$$

$$
\lambda=\frac{(6.626\cdot 10^{-34})(2.998\cdot 10^{8})(6.022\cdot10^{23})}{(-533000)}=-224nm
$$

Obviously the length can’t be negative so I just so I just put it as positive, but is there a mathematical technique for situations like this? I’m just trying to learn.

Comment: All of those numbers are positive. I suspect your error is in using our calculator.

Comment: damn the denominator was meant to be negative @johndouma I edited

Comment: @Nickotine How come the value of $\;j\cdot mol\;$ is negative ?

Comment: This isn't really a math question (certainly not a `linear-algebra` question). Maybe the [Physics StackExchange](https://physics.stackexchange.com) would be a better place for it.

Comment: it’s just how do I mathematically deal with this wrong negative value? @blue not sure what to tag this as

Comment: because: $$bondBreakEnergy=bondEnergyReactants-bondEnergyProducts$$ where the products have a higher bond energy value @donantonio

Comment: @Nickotine: Whether a negative value of a physics-oriented calculation has a valid interpretation is a question for physicists. (As for tagging ... Maybe `soft-question`?)

Comment: Photons cannot have negative energy.

Comment: @blue changed it but is there even a mathematical situation where you have to deal with an expected negative?

Comment: this is like when a physicist says a ball has a positive speed value when going up and a negative value when going down, I thought they got this from maths?

Comment: @Nickotine: *Mathematically*, if I multiply and/or divide an odd number of negative values, I *expect* to get a negative result. I personally can't speak to what's expected *scientifically* here.

Comment: @blue I thought science got all their stuff from you guys, mathematicians?

Comment: @Nickotine: Comments aren't for discussion. I have nothing more to contribute here. Good luck to you! :)

Comment: sorry posting this here shall I just delete it or can it be moved?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just make one of the other values negative as well, for example, let $c=-2.998\cdot 10^{8}\ m\cdot s^{—1}$. Then you get a positive length.

Comment: but are you just ‘allowed’ to do that? @JMP

Comment: Well, $c=\pm\sqrt{\frac{E}{m}}$. so yes you are!

Comment: what the hell how did you come up with that? See I knew mathematicians would give me some crazy good answer that’s why I posted this here, thank you so much @JMP

Comment: oh just rearranging $$E=m\cdot c{2}$$ Very smart @JMP